# Toggle one div with same class

Tags: jquery, toggle

How to use *Toggle* when several div have the same class with jQuery? I want to show just one div on click.

#### JavaScript

```
$(".help_content").hide();
$(".help_target").click(function()
{
    $('.help_content').toggle(); // I also tried with $(".help_content").show();
});
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="foo">
    <p class="help_target">
            <a href="#">Click</a>
    </p>
</div>
<p class="help_content">Asia</p>

<div id="some">
    <p class="help_target">
        <a href="#">Click</a>
    </p>
</div>
<p class="help_content">Africa</p>
```

I can't use *next()* since .help_content is not a descendant of .help_target. (I want to use .help_target in fieldsets and display .help_content out of fieldsets).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(".help_content").hide();
$(".help_target").click(function()
{
    $(this).parent().next('.help_content').toggle();
});
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/X7p28/

Comment: Thank you very much, Matt. I had forgotten parent! Vincent

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
$(this).closest("div").next(".help_content").toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".help_target").click(function()
{
    $(this).parent().next().toggle(); // I also try with $(".help_content").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by calling [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and then [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$(".help_target").click(function()
{
    $(this).parent().next('.help_content').toggle();
});
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/fxPMJ/).**

Comment: I see Matt's answer first, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Why not give the div a unique Id and then call the toggle function

```
$("#help_content_DIV_ID").toggle();
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I had thought. However, I preferred to find a more general solution to implement it later in another more complex project.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.help_target>a').click(function() {
   $('.help_content').hide();
   $(this).closest('.help_target').parent().next('.help_content').eq(0).show();
   return false;
});
```