# Toggling divs within same blocks

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery to toggle between two divs with the following:

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
   $(".module-content").toggle();
   $(".module-edit").toggle();
});
```

I'm going to have several blocks with the same classes down the page in the following way:

```
<div class="module">
   <a class="edit" href="#">Edit</a>
   <div class="module-content">
      <?php echo the_field('company_information'); ?>
   </div>
   <div class="module-edit" style="display:none;">              
      <?php acf_form( $company_information ); ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I only toggle the divs below the edit link but within only that module block?

I know it's very similar to this question - [Toggle one div with same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551888/toggle-one-div-with-same-class) but I just can't get it to work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to select the sibling elements, change your javscript code to this:

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
  $(this).siblings(".module-content, .module-edit").toggle();
});
```

That's now matching the sibling DOM elements with classes `module-content` and `module-edit` and calling the `toggle()` method on all matched elements.

Edit: You requested a way to toggle the link word too, this should work for you:

```
$('.edit').click(function(){

  var link = this;

  // Change the link wording 
  if ($(link).html() == 'edit')
    $(link).html('close');
  else
    $(link).html('edit');

  // Open or close the sibling DIV elements
  $(link).siblings('.module-content, .module-edit').toggle();

  return false;
});
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Is it possible to toggle the link word aswell from edit to close on click?

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar recently. The route I chose - not sure if it is best practice or not - was to fire off the jquery from the onclick attribute on an element. Then pass the current element to your toggle function, so you only affect the divs in context, so to speak.

For example:

```
<div class="module">
  <a class="edit" href="#" onclick="my_toggle(this);">Edit</a>
  <div class="module-content">
    <?php echo the_field('company_information'); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="module-edit" style="display:none;">              
    <?php acf_form( $company_information ); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in your javascript, write something similar to

```
function my_toggle(el){
  // retrieve context element as jquery object
  var jq_el = $(el);
  // toggle
  jq_el.parent().children('.module-content').toggle();
  jq_el.parent().children('.module-edit').toggle();
}
```

The snippet above is not tested, so might contain some mistakes, but I believe the concept is valid.

Comment: I've gone with toomanyredirects answer as it condensed the code down. I have another question though - Is it possible to toggle the link word aswell from edit to close on click?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your followup question exactly. Do you mean to say you want to switch between the text "Edit" and "Close on click"?
If so, just add two span elements inside the link, one with "edit" as text and another one with "close to click". Give each span element a class and add that to your toggle selector.

Comment: Where it says edit in the link, is it possible to change this on click to close?

Comment: just add two span elements inside the link, one with "edit" as text and another one with "close to click". Give each span element a class and add that to your toggle selector. Also, when you load the page made sure the initial visibility state of the click to close span is off.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.siblings(".module-content").toggle();
   $this.siblings(".module-edit").toggle();
});
```

Comment: I've gone with toomanyredirects answer as it condensed the code down. I have another question though - Is it possible to toggle the link word aswell from edit to close on click?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give jQuery some context which `.module-content`/`.module-edit` you want to toggle:

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
   var parent = $(this).parent();
   parent.find(".module-content").toggle();
   parent.find(".module-edit").toggle();
});
```

or

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
   var parent = $(this).parent();
   $(".module-content", parent).toggle();
   $(".module-edit", parent).toggle();
});
```

(Both do the same thing).

BTW, you can simplify the call by toggling both items at the same time:

```
parent.find(".module-content, .module-edit").toggle();
```

Comment: I've gone with toomanyredirects answer as it condensed the code down. I have another question though - Is it possible to toggle the link word aswell from edit to close on click?